# How get data from MariaDB using semicolon delimiter?

Tags: php, regex, mariadb, delimiter

I have database with MariaDB 5.5.x engine. On database I have table "items":

```
Table "items"
------------
ID |name      | location | ... |
--------------------------
1  |some name1| 3;56;23;15;4; |
-----------------------
2  |some name2| 4;8;90;   |
-----------------------
3  |some name3| 6;27;18;87;|
```

I'm looking way to get ID when I know location_ID fx. "90". All locations are in database separated by semicolon (";"). On Zend I used and it worked:

```
where("location REGEXP '(^|[[.semicolon.]])" . $id . "([[.semicolon.]]|$)'");
```

I programming on Slim Framework with MeekroDB Class. My current code in PHP:

```
$DB = new DB(); //MeekroDB PHP Class
$data = $DB::query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE locations REGEXP '(^|[[.semicolon.]])%s([[.semicolon.]]|$)'" , $id);
```

$id is integer. I get error:

> QUERY: SELECT * FROM items WHERE location REGEXP
>   '(^|[[.semicolon.]])'1'([[.semicolon.]]|$)' ERROR: You have an error
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB
>   server version for the right syntax to use near
>   '1'([[.semicolon.]]|$)'' at line 1

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET('87', REPLACE('6;27;18;87', ';', ','));
+----------------------------------------------------+
| FIND_IN_SET('87', REPLACE('6;27;18;87', ';', ',')) |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                  4 |
+----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

That is,

1. change semicolon to comma
2. `FIND_IN_SET()` to search
3. test against 0 to see if it is present.  0=false, >0 = true.

Your code would be something like

```
DB::query("SELECT * FROM items
           WHERE FIND_IN_SET(%s, REPLACE(locations, ';', ','))",
      $id);
```

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB 5.5.x doesn't have [[.semicolon.]], use a plain semicolon instead:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE location REGEXP '(^|;)8(;|$)'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c5cb/1

Before MariaDB 10.0.5 the POSIX 1003.2 compliant regular expression library was used that doesn't have [[.semicolon.]]. From MariaDB 10.0.5 on the PCRE library is used that supports [[.semicolon.]]. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/regular-expressions-overview/

Comment: Thank you Julian! It is what I looking for. It's working:

$data = $DB::query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE locations REGEXP '(^|;)%d(;|$)'" , $id);